# Disable jsf form int validation

Tags: validation, jsf

I have a form in jsf for which I have created a special validator class that checks if the field is: null, empty, valid, number etc. This class throws an exception with a message if the input is not valid. The problem is that when I write letters in the input field (the input should be an int!) I get the default validation message instead of the custom one. How can I disable the default validation message?

Here is an image with the default validation message:

[image]

JSF code:

```
<h:form>
            <h:inputText value="#{deleteEmployeeBean.employeeId}"
                id="employeeId" name="employeeId">
                <f:validator validatorId="idValidator" for="employeeId"></f:validator>
            </h:inputText>
            <h:message for="employeeId" style="color: red;"></h:message>
            <h:commandButton action="#{deleteEmployeeBean.loadEmployee}"
                value="#{content.searchButton}"></h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
```

Comment: I'm surprised it was upvoted. Please provide a [mcve]. We cannot do much with an image.

Comment: This - and does the `validatorMessage` attribute of `h:inputText` help?

Comment: I updated my post. The custom validator works, but it seems that when the form expects a number, the JSF shows the default message instead the custom one from my validator.

Comment: I think you run into bean validation, but a MCVE is needed to check that.

Comment: @jasperdevries: co-worker? Or two accounts?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `validatorMessage` for your  `f:validator`

```
<h:inputText value="#{deleteEmployeeBean.employeeId}"
            id="employeeId" name="employeeId" validatorMessage="your message">
            <f:validator validatorId="idValidator" for="employeeId"></f:validator>
 </h:inputText>
```

or you can use this for let user insert just number

```
    <h:inputText value="#{deleteEmployeeBean.employeeId}"
      id="employeeId" name="employeeId" validatorMessage="your message" 
      onkeypress="if(event.which &lt; 48 || event.which &gt; 57 ) if(event.which != 8) return false;">
       <f:validator validatorId="idValidator" for="employeeId"></f:validator>
   </h:inputText>
```